# Changing images.xcassets resource to 'Device Specific' triggers a compilation error

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several resources in the images.xcassets, all of them as vectors for devices "Universal" configuration. And it is working just fine.

But, when I change one of them to devices "Specific" in order to specify a different resource for iPad, the project doesn't compile anymore.

It is the single unique change that causes this issue, and furthermore, the error is generic at best:

```
2015-02-03 10:28:32.225 ibtoold[14561:217936] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-6608/DVTKit/CocoaClassCategories/DVTNSImageAdditions.m:305
Details:  Assertion failed: [scaleFactor doubleValue] > 0.0
Object:   <NSImage>
Method:   +dvt_imageWithSize:scaleFactors:flipped:forRenderingIntoContext:fromCommands:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa813d29420>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints: None
Backtrace:
0  0x000000011006124a -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
1  0x0000000110060c9f _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
2  0x0000000110060f8e _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
3  0x0000000110060ef0 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
4  0x000000011341cfd4 +[NSImage(DVTNSImageAdditions) dvt_imageWithSize:scaleFactors:flipped:forRenderingIntoContext:fromCommands:] (in DVTKit)
5  0x00000001132c6d7b +[NSImage(DVTNSImageAdditions) dvt_imageWithSize:scaleFactors:flipped:fromCommands:] (in DVTKit)
6  0x0000000116ccb392 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
7  0x0000000116ccc003 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
8  0x0000000116ccc33f (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
9  0x0000000110f4ce71 -[IBICAbstractPlatformAdapter compilePNGImageSetReps:options:queue:completionHandler:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
10  0x0000000116cca562 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
11  0x0000000116ccaa9c (in IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration)
12  0x000000010fe62b65 (in ibtoold)
13  0x000000010fe642db (in ibtoold)
14  0x000000010fe6487e (in ibtoold)
15  0x000000010fe723f7 (in ibtoold)
16  0x000000010fe72947 (in ibtoold)
17  0x000000010fe72817 (in ibtoold)
18  0x000000010fe61c3f (in ibtoold)
19  0x000000010fe71fe1 (in ibtoold)
20  0x000000010fe71238 (in ibtoold)
21  0x00007fff8fc765c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/actool failed with exit code 255
```